# DynamoDB Java SDK - QueryRequest with IN clause

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

The Javadoc of `software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.QueryRequest.expressionAttributeValues()` says a following query can be done:

`ProductStatus IN (:avail, :back, :disc)`

where the values are passed in in "ExpressionAttributeValues" as follows:

`{ ":avail":{"S":"Available"}, ":back":{"S":"Backordered"}, ":disc":{"S":"Discontinued"} }`

I'm now trying to figure how

`QueryRequest.expressionAttributeValues` is the following `Map`:

`Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues)`

there doesn't seem to be any other way to pass expression values to the expression defined in `QueryRequest.keyConditionExpression()`

I specifically looked for a way to pass in a JSON expression -- can't find any.
skipped the legacy methods-- `QueryRequest.keyConditions()` and some others.

i tried

```
  QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest
            .builder().tableName("tablename")
            .indexName("user-index")
            .keyConditionExpression("index-ID IN (:key0, :key1, :key2)"
            .expressionAttributeValues(keys)
            .build();
```

where `Map<String, Map<String, AttributeValue>> keys` looks like the following when i print this `Map` with its `toString()`:

```
{:key2=AttributeValue(S=5555550), :key1=AttributeValue(S=5555551), :key0=AttributeValue(S=5555552)}
```

the following exception is thrown to this:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "":key1"" (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: R986SKT4JTK02C57HD0P8591TVQV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:125)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:41)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:30)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:73)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:171)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DefaultDynamoDbClient.query(DefaultDynamoDbClient.java:4372)
```

i also tried surrounding the key-s with quotes along with some other variations:

```
{":key2"=AttributeValue(S=5555550), ":key1"=AttributeValue(S=5555551), ":key0"=AttributeValue(S=5555552)}
```

Will greatly appreciate the help.
Wore me out.

//==================

UPDATE: i'm aware of the direct Restful call via a script to AWS server, but we're looking for the Java solution.

Comment: You cannot use JSON in the manner you are trying to do. If you want to use SQL like syntax, you can use PartiQL. Here is a complete example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/ScenarioPartiQ.java

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible for a `Query` using `KeyConditionExpression`.

A `KeyConditionExpression` requires an equals `=` comparative on a single partition key only, multiple keys using `IN` or `OR` or `AND` are now allowed.

> Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a sort key value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression.

[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

---

The only API that allows syntax similar to what you are creating is PartiQL `ExecuteStatement` where you can pass in up to 50 partition keys as part of an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK IN [1,2...50]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html

Comment: yeah, i've seen that one too. but then what's that thing in `QueryRequest.expressionAttributeValues()` javadoc?

Comment: expressionAttributeValues acts as a placeholder for you attribute values, this is not related to querying multiple items in a single request.